# Combos with shift not working in emacs on console

Tags: emacs, console, keyboard-layout

I'm running emacs 24.3.1 on a system with a console-only minimal install of Debian Jessie.

Non of the keybindings that involve the shift key works in emacs (except shift to modify upper case). These are the combos I'm missing (all important for editing tree structure in org-mode):

```
M-S-RET
C-S-RET
M-S-LEFT
M-S-RIGHT
M-S-UP
M-S-DOWM
```

Neither register as anything but RET (new line) or arrow movement. Tried running both `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` and `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but neither gives me relevant options to solve the problem.

**EDIT:** found [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html#TTY-keys) from org manual. Turns out that it's a well known problem that the speed keys can take pretty good care of.

To activate speed keys:
    (setq org-use-speed-commands t)

Then when you're at the beginning of a headline:

```
M-S-LEFT = L 
M-S-RIGHT = R
M-S-UP = U
M-S-DOWM = D
```

As for:
    M-S-RET
    C-S-RET

Custom speed keys can quite easily be set for those.

But workaround aside I would still like to hear from folks who knows how to get normal function for shift key outside of X. It is a text-based environment after all, I need all the keys I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html) from org manual. Turns out that it's a well-known problem that the speed keys can take pretty good care of.

To activate speed keys:

(setq org-use-speed-commands t)

Then when you're at the beginning of a headline:

```
M-S-LEFT = L 
M-S-RIGHT = R
M-S-UP = U
M-S-DOWM = D
```

As for:

```
M-S-RET 
C-S-RET
```

Custom speed keys can quite easily be set for those.